# List all files of a directory using Javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying the get all filenames stored in local directories which are named like a date format e.g /190701 (1st July 2019). I started using a javascript calendar to simulate or get the name of my local directory jut by clicking, but the next steep is to get all filenames which need to be showed into a HTML local web.

Here is the javascript line:

```
element.innerHTML = '<a href="some/directory"' + year[2]+year[3] +month+day+ '>' + element.textContent + '</a>';
```

But not sure how can I show all files names and link the javascript function with my html.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't get directory access directly from the browser. You need to have a backend to do that, such as [node](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Comment: You can't do something like that on the front end, you need a backend programming language to be able to accomplish such a task.